# ASP.Net Core Identity in separate class errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working with ASP.Net Core and attempting to move some of the Identity components into a separate assembly. I moved `ApplicationDbContext` and `ApplicationUser` into an assembly called `DataModels`. (`ApplicationUser` is in the `Models` folder/namespace of `DataModels`.)

In the WebApplication `Startup.cs` I reference this assembly and everything compiles fine. I updated the AccountController to correctly reference this as well.

When I start up my app, I receive this:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; private set; }
```

My Startup.cs has this:

```
using DataModels.Models;
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<DataModels.ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataModels.ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Obviously I'm not specifying the DataModels assembly somewhere, I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that it was referenced in these files:

```
_LoginPartial.cshtml
Login.cshtml
```

I needed to update those files with this:

```
@using DataModels.Models
```